# setup git on an existing project in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, version-control, amazon-ec2, versioning

Need to use version control in one of the old project which resides in Amazon EC2 instance. Steps performed:

```
/www/box/
```

1. Installed GIT on the server and initialised the folder /box/

   ```
   git init
   ```
2. Cloned the project in local computer
3. Changed a file and tried to push but received error

   ```
   git push origin master
   Error: Updating the current branch in a non bare repository is denied
   ```
4. Then created another repo folder on server and used --bare tag to initialize

   ```
   /www/repos/
   git init --bare
   ```
5. PUSH command works well on this repository
6. Then added another REMOTE URL to the old project location
       git remote add production ssh:---/www/box/

Questions:

- git push gives me the same error when pushing on to the production repo. How do I push to this production repo?

  ```
  git push production master
  Error: .... non bare repository is denied
  ```
- found lots of tutorial using HOOKS, still confused if using HOOKS is a normal method to push in GIT

Answer (score 0):

In order to push to a remote repository you need two things:

1) The remote repository should be init with the --bare

2) You need to add the remote repository to your local git with "git add remote"

You don't need hooks for a normal push operation.